# Determine if the given set is a subspace of Pn for an appropriate value of n.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have encountered the following problem that I am struggling with:

Prove that:

(i) The set of all polynomials $f(x)$ in the variable $x$ of the form $f(x) = ax^3$
for some constant $a$ is a subspace of the vector space of all polynomials.

(ii) The set of all polynomials $f(x)$ in the variable $x$ of the form $f(x) = a+x^3$
for some constant $a$ is not a subspace of the vector space of all polynomials.

The solutions in the textbook are:
(i) Since the set is $Span\{t^2\}$, the set is a subset.

(ii) The zero vector is not a subset.

I do not fully understand these explanations. In particular, I do not understand how to prove that the zero vector is not a subset. Can you provide more detailed explanations?

Comment: For (i), it is ${\rm span}\,(x^3)$, that is all linear combinations fo the monomial $x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

(i) Let us denote by $P$ the set of polynomials in (i) and $\phi(x)=x^3$ . Then

$$P= span \{\phi\}.$$ The span of a set is always a subspace.

(ii) Let us denote by $Q$ the set of polynomials in (ii) and $\psi$ the null - polynomial. Then $ \psi \notin Q.$ Hence $Q$ is not a subspace.